# passport facebook strategy failed to get user's education

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, passport.js

I'm trying to implement login with facebook using passport. Things worked well but I couldn't get certains fields from the user.

```
// Sign in with Facebook
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
  callbackURL: '/auth/facebook/callback',
  profileFields: ['name', 'email', 'gender', 'location', 'education','hometown'],
  passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
console.log(profile);
})
```

I have name, email, gender and location but not education and hometown. Why is it so?

Comment: did you ask for the required permissions in your login code?

Comment: @luschn what permission? I tried `app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email','user_education_history','user_location'] }));
`
`

Comment: there is "user_hometown" too

Comment: make sure you actually get asked for those permissions in the authorization popup